# Was Kornbluth the first to suggest a future of low-IQ people overwhelming high-IQ "minders"?

Tags: history-of, eugenics, cyril-m-kornbluth

I am referring to his *Little Black Bag* universe which afaik only also includes *The Marching Morons* and inspired *Idiocracy* and to a slight extent *Robocop*.

Note that *The Time Machine* is not really an example of this -- the Eloi/Morlock division is not implied to be because lower-IQ reproduce faster and the Morlock are not really minders but more like farmers.

It seems to me that Kornbluth was very influenced by the ideas of the eugenics movement. Other stories have eugenics of a form implemented (like in *Brave New World*) whereas in Kornbluth, eugenics is nodded to but only because it is not implemented.

Comment: _[The Space Merchants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Merchants)_ is supposed to be a run-up to "The Little Black Bag" and "The Marching Morons".

Comment: If you're ruling out _The Time Machine_, does that rule out other post-holocaust stories with a "devolved" population such as _[Darkness and Dawn](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/7463/pg7463.txt)_ (1914) by George Allan England?

Comment: The final chapter of [Search the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_the_Sky) has a similar theme but post-dates The Marching Morons